# java compare two records same id in two different types of lists in java

Tags: java, spring, list, arraylist, stream

class Student: String name, String register, String dept, Integer pendingCollegeFee
class HostelStudent: String name, String register, Integer pendingHostelFee, Integer pendingMessFee
and list of two objects:

1. List of Student            List<Student> CollegeStudents;
2. List of HostelStudent      List<HostelStudent> HostelStudents;

Now i want to compare records in both lists having same name and register number and then need to call a method with the record whose values are both in two lists to

```
isThereAnyPendingFees(Student s, HostelStudent hs) {
     return(s.getPendingCollegeFee() + hs.getPendingHostelFee() + hs.getPendingMessFee() !=0
}
```

can anyone help me in acheiving this in O(nlogn)or even less because the records length in list is very high.

Answer (score 1):

Sort each list by name and register number: O(n logn).

Loop through the first list, and for each element binary search the other list for a match, then perform whatever operations are needed on the two matching elements. Binary search is O(logn), so this is overall O(n logn).

Both steps are O(n logn), so the algorithm is still O(nlogn)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would extend the Student class in the HostelStudent class. You're using multiple variables at once.

Student.cs:

```
class Student {

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String register;
    etc...

    public Student(long id, String name, String register) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.register = register;
    }
}
```

HostelStudent.cs:

```
class HostelStudent extends Student {

    private Integer pendingHostelFee;
    etc...

    public HostelStudent(long id, String name, String register, Integer pendingHostelFee) {
        super(id, name, register);
        this.pendingHostelFee = pendingHostelFee;
    }
}
```

You can make a list of Student's `List<Student>` and a list for HostelStudent's `List<HostelStudent>`. After filling the lists you can loop through them en check if the values are the same. (Don't forget your getters/setters).

Answer (score 0):

Make a class representing just an 'identity' (so, presumably, name+register, though it sounds like you've misjudged the situation and you really want just 'register' to be the unique key, in which case you can just use String), and then instead of lists, use maps:

`Map<StudentId, Student>` and `Map<StudentId, HostelStudent>`.

These do lookups far quicker.

Alternatively, sort your lists on for example `register`, then you can use binary search (which you can find in the Collections class) which is also orders of magnitude faster than just searching a list. However, you'd have to grab the source of binary search (or use wikipedia to understand the algorithm; you want to use a reigster+name combo to find an entry, you won't have an actual instance of HostelStudent to search for.

All in all the map solution is going to be much, much simpler. I strongly advise you go with that.